# Open Mobile camera through voice in android studio

Tags: android, voice

I want to know that is it possible to open camera through voice in android studio. I want to build app for visually impaired which is fully based on user voice. In my application there is only two mode one is **Document reading** and other is **Note Detection** so when user say document reading or note detection then automatically camera will open and take picture. Let me know if anyone knows about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its is possible through `SpeechRecognizer`. `SpeechRecognizer` is android feature using this we can speech to text.Visit  this blog [Speech to text](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Using Speech-to-text

You have to use the `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH`

here is the sample code

```
/**
     * Showing google speech input dialog
     * */
    private void promptSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

then you can get the text as

```
/**
     * Receiving speech input
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

        }
    }
```

After that you can check the text if its equal to your desired input i.e `Document reading || Note Detection` then you can open your Camera activity implementation.

Please refer this link for more details and full code about ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH
[link](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/)